# Using ffmpeg to cut up mkv video

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

I'm completely lost with ffmpeg
I got an mkv of 4:33 duration and I'd like to cut out the end from 4:20

I tried different ways:

1) Does not cut at all

```
~ > ffmpeg -t 00:04:20 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -i output3.mkv output3-cut.mkv
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:27:34, gcc: 4.4.3

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 15.00 (15/1)
Input #0, matroska, from 'output3.mkv':
  Duration: 00:04:34.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 1808x944, PAR 1:1 DAR 113:59, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
File 'output3-cut.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'output3-cut.mkv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 1808x944 [PAR 1:1 DAR 113:59], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame= 4109 fps=3864 q=-1.0 Lsize=   36017kB time=272.48 bitrate=1082.8kbits/s    
video:33503kB audio:2344kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.477241%
```

2) Cuts to 4:25 if I specify 4m15s 4m05s 4m and other seconds after 4m, with the same resulting file size. It cuts to 3:25 regardless of seconds value if I specify 3m50s or 30m*some value*s

```
~ > ffmpeg -t 4m20s -acodec copy -vcodec copy -i output3.mkv oFFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:27:34, gcc: 4.4.3

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 15.00 (15/1)
Input #0, matroska, from 'output3.mkv':
  Duration: 00:04:34.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 1808x944, PAR 1:1 DAR 113:59, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
File 'output3-cut.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'output3-cut.mkv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 1808x944 [PAR 1:1 DAR 113:59], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame= 4001 fps=3570 q=-1.0 Lsize=   35240kB time=266.71 bitrate=1082.4kbits/s    
video:32781kB audio:2292kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.475784%
utput3-cut.mkv
```

3) Works hard and long time and cuts exactly to 4:20 but makes a huge file, changing file size from 35Mb to 113Mb!!!

```
ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:04:20 -sameq output3-cut.mkv
```

**What is the right way to cut an mkv file?**

ps

I also tried mencoder but it damages an audio track

Comment: By the way, `sameq` does **not** mean "same quality". Just forget that this option exists and never use it again, please :)

Comment: yes, it sounds just like same quality )

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In theory, this is enough:

```
ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -c:v copy -c:a copy output-cut.mkv
```

Read as: Input MKV video, encode 4:20 minutes, copy audio and video bitstream and save them to output file.

If you have problems with synchronization, try re-encoding audio and video:

```
ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac output-cut.mkv
```

Of course, you can specify the video quality with `-crf 23` and the audio quality with `-b:a 192k`, varying those parameters. Read [our FFmpeg blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) for more info.

---

Here's what was wrong about your commands:

- You're using a terribly outdated version of FFmpeg. Please compile it from source or download a precompiled binary from the homepage. This will reduce the possibility of running into bugs.
- `-acodec copy -vcodec copy` can not come *before* the `-i` option. Anything before `-i` tells FFmpeg to decode the input video. There is no "copy decoder" – that doesn't make sense. The order of options is important here. `-c:a copy` and `-c:v copy` come *after* the input option and before the output.
- `-t 4m20s` is the wrong syntax: The duration may be a number in seconds, or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]`.
- `-t` can't come before `-i` either.
- `-ss 00:00:00` is irrelevant, it would just tell FFmpeg to start from the beginning, which it always does.

Comment: I tried ```ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -c:v copy -c:a copy output3-cut.mkv``` and got ```ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-c:v'```

Then  ```ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output3-cut.mkv``` with no luck. It produced the file of the same size and duration. 

Then I tryed ```ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac output3-cut.mkv``` (cause -c:v is unknown) and got ```Unknown encoder 'libfaac'```

I use ffmpeg SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 from deb repo. I guess I'd better compile it from sources.

Comment: Thank you for the url! - I'm going to dive in ffmpeg compilation right now

Comment: The `c:v` syntax isn't supported in older versions. AAC should be available through `libfaac` or `libvo_aacenc`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I just learned that the Zeranoe builds obviously don't bundle `libfaac` (anymore?)

Comment: So, I compiled ffmpeg. Here is the verson: ```git-2012-09-21-7bc7093```

```  built on Sep 21 2012 20:09:06 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 57.100 / 54. 57.100
  libavformat    54. 27.101 / 54. 27.101
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 16.106 /  3. 16.106
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

Comment: I ran ```ffmpeg -i output3.mkv -t 00:04:20 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac output3-cut.mkv``` and video quality degraded significantly. How can I cut the end but keep the same quality?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I'm mistaken. Everything is OK! Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @zuba Glad I could help! :)